# "Duplicate Validator" error when calling a python function that returns pydantic model with custom validator

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have the following code

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

def create_model(additional_data):
    class CustomModel(BaseModel):
        name: str
        additional_field: str
        @validator('name')
        def validate_name(cls, name):
            # Custom validation logic based on additional_data
            if additional_data == 'some_condition':
                # Custom validation for some_condition
                pass
            else:
                # Custom validation for other conditions
                pass
            return name
    return CustomModel

Model1 = create_model("condition1")
Model2 = create_model("condition2") # Gives `duplicate validator function "__main__.create_model.<locals>.CustomModel.validate_name"` error
```

I want to return pydantic model from "create_model" function and the validator logic is different for each call. When I call the "create_model" function twice, I get "duplicate validator" error.

Comment: Have you read the entire error message? Because it literally tells you the solution in the error message: set `allow_reuse=True`

Comment: I wanted to understand what exactly allow_reuse=True does. Does it run both the validators?

Comment: https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/validators/#reuse-validators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given by @Anh doesn't raise any exception but modifying class variable means it will affect the entire class. Model1(...) after creating Model2 will have the additional_data = "condition2". In order to ensure that Model1 and Model2 have different validation logic, we need to return different class with different additional_data. This can be done by returning new class that inherits from CustomModel.

I have modified the code:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class CustomModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    additional_field: str

    @validator('name')
    def validate_name(cls, name):
        # Custom validation logic based on additional_data
        if cls.additional_data == 'some_condition':
            # Custom validation for some_condition
            pass
        else:
            # Custom validation for other conditions
            pass
        return name

def create_model(additional_data):
    class CustomReturnModel(CustomModel):
        pass
    CustomReturnModel.additional_data = additional_data #CustomReturnModel inherits from CustomModel, and for each call to create_model, different class is created. So, CustomReturnModel.additional_data will be different for return
    return CustomReturnModel

Model1 = create_model("condition1")
Model2 = create_model("condition2")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class CustomModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    additional_field: str

    @validator('name')
    def validate_name(cls, name):
        # Custom validation logic based on additional_data
        if cls.additional_data == 'some_condition':
            # Custom validation for some_condition
            pass
        else:
            # Custom validation for other conditions
            pass
        return name

def create_model(additional_data):
    CustomModel.additional_data = additional_data
    return CustomModel

Model1 = create_model("condition1")
Model2 = create_model("condition2")
```

replace this code

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But, Model1 and Model2 should have different validation logic. Changing the class data in Model2 will change the data for Model1 also. (Model1(...) after creating Model2 will have the additional_data = "condition2"). I want Model1 to always have additional_data = "condition1".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You've posted 9 answers so far over the last 24 hours, and most of them are either mostly code with no explanation, appear likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT), or both. A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. For answers where you have not used AI, keep in mind that providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* your code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.